# Use minitrace in a given namespace in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, profiler

I'm using [minitrace](https://github.com/hrydgard/minitrace) to profile performance of my functions in a namesapce `filtration`. However, minitrace does not work if functions like `MTR_BEGIN()` are invoked inside a namespace. The following is my code. My idea is to add namesapce to `minitrace.h`. Any suggestion on having minitrace work in a namesapce?

```
#include "minitrace.h"

namesapce filtration {
    FILE* trace_file = fopen("/tmp/trace", "wb");
    mtr_init_from_stream(trace_file);
    MTR_META_PROCESS_NAME("minitrace_test");
    MTR_META_THREAD_NAME("main thread");
    int long_running_thing_1;
    int long_running_thing_2;
    MTR_START("background", "long_running", &long_running_thing_1);
    MTR_START("background", "long_running", &long_running_thing_2);
    MTR_BEGIN("main", "binary_search");

    binarySearch();

    MTR_END("main", "binary_search");
    MTR_FINISH("background", "long_running", &long_running_thing_1);
    MTR_FINISH("background", "long_running", &long_running_thing_2);
    mtr_flush();
    mtr_shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell why you want to do it like this, and why doesn't work, since the example shouldn't even compile (statements outside of function body).

Comment: You cannot call arbitrary code just from a namespace without appearing in a function body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some functions signature in `minitrace.h`. I think you can add namesapce like `minitrace` to these functions.